# why can't I run scripts in line in my cshtml file?

Tags: razor

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function greySubmit() {
        if (document.getElementById('qa1') != Request.Form[A] || 
        Request.Form[B] || Request.Form[C] || Request.Form[D])
        {
            document.getElementById('submit').disabled();
        }
    }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function returnSubPage() {
        return Redirect("~/Home/Submitted");
    }
    </script>
}
```

When the view runs, these are completely skipped over. Also, these are in my layout file.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/admin")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

I'm confused as to why these won't run? I know they don't because I added breakpoints to my code and it never actually hits these. The file is fairly large, so I think that there maybe could be something overriding it but I want to make sure that I'm not missing something.

Comment: your scripts will rendered, Don't you have any error in browser console? what's Request.Form[A] ?

Comment: @MajidParvin I forgot to change true in the RenderSection line to false, I do get an error I was just fooling around with the code. If it is false, the scripts are simply passed over. The Request.Form[A] is irrelevant to the issue however.